# Requesting to reopen a question

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, minimal-reproducible-example

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559600/unable-to-apply-the-new-syntax-of-using-for-streamwriter) and tried to make a **minimal** example. However, due to unfortunate diagnostics of the error, it wasn't sufficient, so I chose to close it (even deleted). Later on, I realized that I had the issue still but didn't realize what it was, so I undeleted and improved.

I'd like to have it reopened. Is it appropriate?

Comment: You could just have waited for the review to complete...

Comment: @BaummitAugen Not sure which review you're referring to. Please elaborate.

Comment: Your edit put the post in the [reopen review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/28987136), where it would have been reviewed for reopening in the next few hours or so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you've added enough to your question to make it a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/mcve), then yes it can be reopened.

There were already 2 reopen votes when I looked at it, and I cast the final vote to reopen.

Comment: I think MVE is also used occasionally: Minimal *Verifiable* Example?

Comment: @AdrianMole I think MVRCATPE is also one: _Minimum Verifiable Reproducible Complete Absolute Thorough Proper Example_. Is it confirmed? ;)